# Using jQuery event handlers - jQuery newbie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in the process of learning jQuery and feel that I must be missing something. I have a super simple form set up as below:

```
<form name="testform" id="testform" method="post">
    <select type="select" id="searchid">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="searchtext" value="$_POST['value']">
</form>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to automatically submit the form when `#searchid` is changed. I understand how to do this with basic JavaScript, but I need jQuery for other things and need to learn how these things work. The below jQuery snippet seems to me like it should work, but it's not working. Any ideas why?

```
$( "#searchid" ).change( function() {
    $( "#testform" ).submit();
})
```

Comment: You are missing the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added them and it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Have you put the code in document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler?

Comment: I'd suggest starting where we all started out, by reading the documentation, and jQuery now has it's own [**learning center**](http://learn.jquery.com/). An hour of reading and trying some of the examples, and you should be able to make that code work.

Comment: The `ready` handler seems like it's meant to fire off its function when the page is, well, ready, similar to JavaScript's `onload` but firing as soon as the script is ready but before the page fully loads. Am I misunderstanding? Does `ready` have to do something to make other handlers like `change` work?

Comment: Your inputs have no name, what are you trying to post? Probably what you get server side isn't really what you're waiting for. BTW what do you mean with "it doesn't work"? What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: Nothing happens. At all (except the selected value changes). This is a very low level test case. I don't care at this point what values the server is getting. I'm just trying to figure out why the event handler isn't triggering and its function isn't firing.

Comment: Wrapping that all in the `ready` handler did the trick:

    `$( document ).ready( function() {
        $( "#searchid" ).onchange( function()
            $( "#testform" ).submit();
        });
    });

But I still don't understand why. Thank you all for the help. I will keep reading, but I feel like I must have missed something.

Comment: *"But I still don't understand why"* See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can submit the form:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#searchid" ).change( function() {
        $( "#testform" )[0].submit();
        //or this.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Quite close indeed. To make sure that your server-side will receive proper data, **your inputs should have names**.

**EDIT**

The code has been updated to include DOM ready. It's easy to assume that DOM ready is so fundamental and that it may not be an issue. However, it's never safe to make any assumptions.

**Please note** that when creating demos on js fiddle, you may not be required to use DOM ready if the drop down under jQuery version selector says 'onLoad' or 'onDomReady' ... .. as your code will be wrapped in the appropriate event handler by js fiddle anyway.

Comment: It doesn't work unless I wrap it in the `ready` handler. It seems strange to me that the examples I'm seeing don't require that.

Comment: DOM ready is a given, and your comment just came when I thought of including DOM ready. See the updated version. Where is the example? On JS Fiddle?

Comment: I was using the information from the "Learn jQuery" site referenced above well before asking this question.

http://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/

Knowing that these handlers require DOM ready is good, but it would have taken me ages to find that information without this question. :/

Comment: @RMac: Seems like you skipped the introduction: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: I didn't skip that. I just didn't understand it. I've been using event handlers in the HTML like `onchange` before and am new to all this. I didn't make the connection reading that that the HTML `onchange` handler is loaded when the DOM is ready _anyway_. It was an oversight on my part.